Why does SLD apply two Rules
I got three Rules:
<Rule>
  <name>rule1</name>
  <ogc:Filter>....</ogcFilter> 
  <Symbolizer/>
</Rule>

<Rule>
  <name>rule2</name>
  <ogc:Filter>....</ogcFilter>
  <Symbolizer/>
</Rule>

<Rule>
  <name>default_rule</name>
  <ElseFilter/>
  <Symbolizer/>
</Rule>

One feature meet the conditions of Rule1 and Rule2,And GeoServer draw this feature twice,uisng Symbolizer1 and Symbolizer2.
In what way can I make this feature draw once,using the first matching Rule.
Like QGIS ClassifyRenderer.

This is not part of the SLD standard, but if you are using GeoServer, you can add the following tag before closing your FeatureTypeStyle:
<VendorOption name="ruleEvaluation">first</VendorOption>

The normal GeoServer behavior is consistent with the SLD standard, it will execute all matching rules. With the above vendor option, it will stop at the first matching rule instead.

Thank you.It take effect.

The only way to prevent the second rule would be to make the filter not match the feature.

I would add a new rule with the 'And' operator that includes the filters for both rule 1 and 2.
<Rule>
  <name>new_rule</name>
  <ogc:Filter>
     <ogc:And>
        *Filters from rules 1 & 2*
     </ogc:And>
  </ogcFilter>
  <Symbolizer/>
</Rule>

Then alter rule 1 filter to ensure it doesn't match rule 2, either using something like the 'Not' operator or 'PropertyIsNotEqualTo', whatever is most suitable for your data. Then do the same for rule 2, change the filter logic so it doesn't match rule 1.
Documentation: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html
